# JavaScript match before and after underscore

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array in JavaScript. Items in the array are like below:

var people = new Array("michael_51", "mark_57", "graham_44", "paul_22");

I would really like to split the elements before and after the underscore and then use them in a loop.

```
start loop...
(1st Match) - (2nd Match)
end loop...
```

First in the loop match would be (michael) and second would be (51) etc.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not really necessary (apart from the `split`):

```
var people = new Array("michael_51", "mark_57", "graham_44", "paul_22");

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    var data = people[i].split("_");
    alert("(1st Match): "+data[0]+" - (2nd Match): "+data[1]);
}
```

[Try demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/jqeg6/).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for all the replies. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var people = new Array("michael_51", "mark_57", "graham_44", "paul_22");

for (p in people) {
    console.log(people[p].split('_'));
}
```

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/WgEUN/

Answer (score 0):

```
var i, cleanPeople = [];
for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    cleanPeople.push(people[i].split('_'));
}
```